# Is my ansatz for finding $n$-periodic-points of the exponential-function exhaustive?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, periodic-orbit

The following is about getting help for a proof on existence and indexability of periodic points of the exponential-function, here with base $e:=\exp(1)$.

> ***Update** The question is a complete rewriting of the previous formulation of my question which I hope is much better focused and straightforward.*

Let us define $f(z):=\exp(z)$ for $z \in \mathbb C$. Iteration may be denoted by  $f°^1(z)=f(z)$ and $f°^{h+1}(z)=f°^{h}(f°^1(z))$.

***Fixpoints***: it is known (for instance W. Bergweiler<sup>[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3674391/how-to-find-examples-of-periodic-points-of-the-complex-exponential-function-z)</sup>, pg 16),

- that $f$ has infinitely many fixpoints (=$1$-periodic points) $p_1$,
- that all of them are non-real, and
- that all of them are repelling.

They may be ***indexed*** by the branchindex $k \in \mathbb Z$ used in the Lambert-$W(k;z)$-function like $p_{1:k}$.

***Periodic points***: it is further known that for ***all*** $n$ the sets of $n$-periodic points are as well infinite<sup>[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3674391/how-to-find-examples-of-periodic-points-of-the-complex-exponential-function-z)</sup>(pg.16). Let us denote such a set from now  $\mathbb P_n$. So, in generalization of the indexing of $1$-periodic points, one might say, that the set $\mathbb P$ of all $\mathbb P_n , \text{with } n=1 \ldots \infty $ can be indexed by $\mathbb Z^\infty$.
But I think this is not precise enough; I assume, and would like to prove,

- ***(Conj. 1)*** that actually $\mathbb P_n$ can exactly be indexed by $\mathbb Z^n$        $\qquad \Leftarrow \mathbb {\text{problem to be proved}}$

---

***For my approach arguing for (Conj. 1)*** I refer to the property, that a fixed- or periodic points, which is repelling for iteration over function $f()$, is attracting for iteration over its inverse, which means is attracting for the iteration over the  $\log()$-function. From Bergweiler, pg. 17, I take, that *all* periodic points are repelling on iteration on $f()$ and thus are *all* attracting for its inverse.

For convenience of further notation let us define $\log()$ as $g(x):=\log(x)$ and as well the iteration $g°^1(z)=g(z)$ and $g°^{h+1}(z)=g°^{h}(g°^1(z))$.

To make $g()$ a true inverse of $f()$, we'll need the branch index(es) explicite, so let us simply extend the notation
$$g(x,k):=\log(x) + k \cdot C \qquad \text{where } C=2 \pi î$$
This allows to make precisely for some fixed $z$
$$    g(f(z),0)=z $$
but for the reversion of some $z'=z + k\cdot C$ we need
$$  g(f(z'),k)=g(f(z+k\cdot C),k) =g(f(z),k)=z+k \cdot C=z'  $$

For adressing periodic points of period-length $n$ we expand the notation further
$$ \begin{array}{}  g(z,[k_1])&:= g(z,k_1) \\
  g(z,[k_1,k_2])&:= g(g(z,k_1),k_2) \\
g(z,[k_1,k_2,...,k_n])&:= g(...g(g(z,k_1),k_2)...,k_n) \\
 &\small \text{where all $k_j \in \mathbb Z$}\\
\end{array}$$

Finally I use $K_n:=[k_1,k_2,...,k_n]$ for the vector of branch-indexes. With this I conjecture now the following:

1. iterations of each expression $z_{i+1}=g(z_i,K_n)$ are attracting.
2. we can approximate *any* periodic point $p_{n,K}$ by simple fixed-point iteration of the previous with some suitable initial value $z_0 \ne 0$ according to $$p_{n,K} = \lim_{i \to \infty} z_{i+1}=g(z_i,K_n)$$ (of course we can increase speed of approximation when Newton-iteration on $g()$ follows).
3. the iteration for a given $K_n$ is attracting over the whole complex plane except for the initial values $z_0 \in \{0,1,e,e^e,...\}$.
   Non uniqueness occurs only for $K=[0]$ (and its non-primitive repetitions $K=[0,0]$,... $K=[0,0,...,0]$) in that the initial value $z_0$ is relevant for to converge towards the $1$-periodic point either in the upper or in the lower half plane.
4. ***Main conjecture to be proved:*** All $n$-periodic points with the exception of the conjugated primary fixed points $p_{1:[0]}$ and $\overline {p_{1:[0]}}$ (which have the same branch index-vector $K=[0]$) are in bijection to the indexes $K_n$ and can be approximated by simple fixed-point iteration over $g(z,K_n)$ (if desired followed by Newton-iteration on $g(z,K_n)$ to speed up convergence).

*Remark: I have seen, that with exponential bases different from $e:=exp(1)$ spuriously non-uniquenesses and non-existences of $n$-periodic points occur, which I cannot yet nail down except by giving a couple of heuristic examples. However, large surveys on the exponential with base $e$ -as discussed here- seem to have only that one exception as mentioned in (3.).*

---

An illustration of periodic points of periods $n=1..5$ . Those were found by screening the square $-4-4î...4+4î$ on the complex plane in steps by $1/40$ with the newton-iteration applied. The list has then been checked whether they all agree with the $K_n$-indexing scheme; all found periodic points have a valid $K$-index.
[image: picture]

---

A long & wide discussion (using other bases than $e$, and using another ansatz for partial solutions) can be found at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3707910/1714)

---

***A handful of used literature:*** I've found some resources on fixed points and their properties for the exponential function base $e$, but less about $n$-periodic points. The most fruitful so far was the habilitation of Walter Bergweiler, 1991. If there are more comprehensive texts (optimally online available), please leave a comment.

<sup>[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3674391/how-to-find-examples-of-periodic-points-of-the-complex-exponential-function-z)</sup>*Bergweiler, Walter*, Periodische Punkte bei der Iteration ganzer Funktionen, Aachen: Rheinisch-Westfälische Techn. Hochsch., Math.-Naturwiss. Fak., Habil.-Schr. 51 S. (1991). [ZBL0728.30021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0728.30021).

Pg.16:

- *"Dieses Ergebnis wurde im Jahre 1948 duch Rosenbloom verallgemeinert, der zeigte, daß für jedes $n \gt 2$ unendlich viele periodische Punkte der Periode $n$ existieren"*
- *"Baker im Jahre 1960 (...) bewies (...), daß höchstens eine (von $f$ abhängige) natürliche Zahl $n$ existiert mit der Eigenschaft, daß $f$ nur endlich viele periodische Punkte der primitive Periode $n$ hat."*

Pg. 17:

- *"Satz 2: Es sei $f$ eine ganze transendente Funktion und es sei $n \ge 2$. Dann hat $f$ unendlich viele abstoßende periodische Punkte der primitiven Periode $n$."*
- *"Wir bemerken noch, daß ganze Funktionen keine anziehenden periodischen Punkte zu haben brauchen. Ein Beispiel, (...) ist durch $f(z)=e^z$ gegeben."*

*Additional readings:*

*Hellmuth Kneser*, [**Real analytic solutions of the equation $φ(φ(x))=e^x$ and related functional equations. (Reelle analytische Lösungen der Gleichung $φ(φ(x))=e^x$ und verwandter Funktionalgleichungen.)**], J. Reine Angew. Math. 187, 56-67 (1949)(German).[Zbl0035.04801](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0035.04801).[4](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0035.04801)

*Shen, Zhaiming; Rempe-Gillen, Lasse*, [**The exponential map is chaotic: an invitation to transcendental dynamics**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.10.919), Am. Math. Mon. 122, No. 10, 919-940 (2015). [ZBL1361.37002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1361.37002).[5](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1361.37002)
*Here general aspects of the set of $n$-periodic points are presented in existence-theorems. Even the concept of infinite non-periodic, but not diverging-to-infinity, orbits -as part of the general chaotic behaviour- is covered by the list of theorems.(G.H.)*

An introductory article which deals with the question of $\mathbb P_1$ (fixed-) points on the branches of the $\log()$-function by Stanislav Sykora (2016) [at his web-space](http://ebyte.it/library/docs/math16/FixedPointsExp.html).

Comment: P.s. I ask here after I couldn't get much resonance in my questions in MSE here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3674391  and here
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3677280  . With the question here at MO I tried to put more clarity (and also I focused it to the problem of exhaustivity). I hope this problem is not felt inappropriate for the MO...